# Can't figure out how to make google maps work with drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I'm pretty new to drupal and that kind of website development. I've been trying to install certain modules to try and make a text field that would auto complete an address as it's typed.

Something like this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?csw=1

Without the map and all the extra fields. **Just** the text field.

---

**What I've Tried**

I have installed modules:

geophp

[google maps api v3](https://drupal.org/project/gm3)

The problem I'm having is i'm not really even certain how to use these modules. From where do I actually set up the options on how to display this on what part of my webpage? I've had success installing other modules, but this one is really confusing me.

Would I need to utalize the API by plain HTML/Javascript in a content block?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Geocoder Autocomplete](https://drupal.org/project/geocoder_autocomplete) module. There is also a [Geocoder Addressfield sandbox] module[2](https://drupal.org/sandbox/jlyon/1702018).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend OpenLayers (/project/openlayers) for your geocoding work. Although not as straight forward as some modules I believe there is more versatility. Here is a very robust setup that points in your direction:

https://groups.drupal.org/node/76848

A simpler route might be the Geocoder (/project/geocoder) module. Again, use with OpenLayers (/project/openlayers). There is tutorial at the bottom of the module page: http://vimeo.com/38558646.

Comment: OpenLayers module is used to display locations, points or other map elements. It uses other modules to get the addresses.